# ¿Cuál es el uso y significado de _nombre __nombre o __nombre__ en python?

Tags: python

¿Cuál es el significado de; guión bajo, doble guión bajo, etc? al nombrar objetos en python ?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Esto se encuentra en la documentación,

[Python: Estilos de denominación](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#descriptive-naming-styles) (inglés)

Donde se describe lo que comenta Darkhogg

> Además, las siguientes formas especiales con iniciales o finales
>   subrayados son reconocidos (estos generalmente se pueden combinar con
>   cualquier convencion):
>
> **_single_leading_underscore**: débil indicador de "uso interno". Por ejemplo: `from M import *` no importa objetos cuyo nombre inicia con
>   guión bajo.
>
> **single_trailing_underscore_**: usado por convención para evitar conflictos con la palabra clave (keyword) `Python`, por ejemplo,
>
> ```
>  Tkinter.Toplevel(master, class_='ClassName')
> ```
>
> **__double_leading_underscore**: al nombrar un atributo de clase, invoca renombrado de nombres (dentro de la clase FooBar, `__boo` se
>   convierte a `_FooBar__boo;`).
>
> **__double_leading_and_trailing_underscore__**: objetos "mágicos" o atributos que viven en espacios de nombres controlados por el usuario.
>   Por ejemplo: `__init__` , `__import__` o `__file__`. Nunca inventar
>   tales nombres; únicamente usarlos como son documentados.

Answer (score 14):

- `_nombre` (prefijo con un único guión bajo): Indica que dicho nombre es de uso interno.  Al importar un módulo con `from m import *`, ningún nombre que comience con `_` se importará.

  También se utiliza en clases como una forma de indicar que un cierto método es para uso interno y no forma parte de la API pública, pero esto es convención y el lenguaje no le da ningún significado especial.
- [`__nombre`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html#tut-private) (prefijo con doble guión bajo, máximo un guión bajo de sufijo): Indica que cierto miembro de una clase es privado y convierte el nombre mediante *name mangling* a `_clase__nombre`, donde clase es el nombre de la clase actual.

  La intención de la conversión de nombres es evitar accidentes, por ejemplo, al heredar de una clase con atributos o métodos "privados".  No impide en ningún caso su sobreescritura o acceso en general.
- `__nombre__` (prefijo *y* sufijo con doble guión bajo): Indica que se trata de un nombre *mágico*.  Se trata en general o bien de variables especiales, o bien de métodos con un significado o comportamiento especiales dentro del lenguaje.  *Nunca definas tus propios nombres mágicos, solo utilízalos tal como estén documentados*.

Puedes encontrar estas convenciones en el [PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#id32).