# Atributos protegidos en Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, atributos

Que son atributos protegidos?
En que sentido colocarle un guion bajo "_" al nombre de "algo" en una clase lo convierte en un atributos protegido?

teniendo el siguiente código:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name

class Usuario(Person):
    pass

class Usuario2(Usuario):
    pass

class Final(Usuario2):
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        super().__init__(nombre)

usr = Final("Miguel")
print(usr._name)
#--------------------------------
usr._name = "Juan"
print(usr._name)
```

De igual manera puedo acceder y modificar a _name desde cualquier nivel de subclase. Cosa que no ocurriría de ser __name.

Gracias.
Saludos

Comment: Este es uno de los temas recurrentes que tiene python. Puede echar un vistazo a otras preguntas como [`¿Cuál es el uso y significado de _nombre __nombre o __nombre__ en python?`](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/4819/cu%C3%A1l-es-el-uso-y-significado-de-nombre-nombre-o-nombre-en-python/4835) y [Problemas para acceder a un atributo privado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/346373/problemas-para-acceder-a-un-atributo-privado/346377). Si hay algo que no entiendas, vuelve y pregunta lo que no veas claro.

Answer (score 1):

Los nombres que comienzan con doble barra son privados.

> __*
>
> Class-private names. Names in this category, when used within
> the context of a class definition, are re-written to use a
> mangled form to help avoid name clashes between “private”
> attributes of base and derived classes.

El nombre del atributo se cambia para dificultar el acceso, pero el atributo en si todavía está accesible usando la forma "_nombreClase__nombreAtributo". La clase en cuestión es aquella donde está definido el atributo (`Persona`) en tu ejemplo, no la clase final instanciada (`Final`)

Verificalo usando esta versión de tu código. Agregue una segunda variable usr2 para comprobar que hablamos de un atributo de la instancia, no de la clase.

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name):
        self.__name = name

class Usuario(Person):
    pass

class Usuario2(Usuario):
    pass

class Final(Usuario2):
    def __init__(self, nombre):
        super().__init__(nombre)

usr = Final("Miguel")
print("usr=", usr._Person__name)
#--------------------------------
usr._Person__name = "Juan"
print("usr=", usr._Person__name)
usr2 = Final("Jorge")
print("---")
usr2._Person__name = "Rodrigo"
print("usr=", usr._Person__name)
print("usr2=", usr2._Person__name)
```

produce

```
usr= Miguel
usr= Juan
---
usr= Juan
usr2= Rodrigo
```